# Error in downlading TCGA Data using GDC-client tool kit

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, bioinformatics

I am trying to fetch the clinical data of >1000 files from TCGA. I have used GDC-client tool kit
But it is showing the below error.

/tmp/_MEIkaerqR/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a 2.7.x release that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.

I have updated the python version too.My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Probably use `python3` instead of `python`, provided the tool you are trying to use supports the supported and recommended version of Python. If not, probably look for a different tool.

Comment: i already installed python3 . But that also shows same error.

Comment: "Support for your Python version is deprecated"...? Then I'm pretty sure you still tried `python`, not `python3`. Which command exactly are you typing at the prompt?

Comment: i tried to use gc -tool kit by typing this cmd   :   ./gdc-client

Comment: From where? The [current Github source](https://github.com/NCI-GDC/gdc-client/blob/develop/bin/gdc-client) certainly uses `#!/usr/bin/env python3` which could not possibly end up executing Python 2 on a correctly configured system. But I'm guessing maybe you have a really old version from somewhere...?